# Pulling e-mail addresses into excel with VBA from outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, office-automation

At work I have two e-mail accounts in outlook.  One is an individual e-mail and the other is a general department e-mail.

How would I use VBA to get excel to access the general e-mail and pull the sender of each e-mail into a string?  I need to iterate over each e-mail in the inbox ignoring e-mails in any sub folders.

Here's the code I've written so far.  Hopefully I'm at least on the right track.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim emailApp As Outlook.Application, emailNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim oFolder As MAPIFolder, oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim iSelect As Outlook.AccountSelector, iBox As Outlook.Account

Dim tEmailAddress As String

Set emailApp = New Outlook.Application
Set emailNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = emailNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'I think im on the right track here.......
Set iBox = iSelect.SelectedAccount

For Each oMail In oFolder.Items
    
    tEmailAddress = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
    'Do other stuff for the project.........

Next

End Sub
```

EDIT: Posting a completed code sample for the next person who is having this problem.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim emailApplication As Outlook.Application, emailAccounts As Outlook.Accounts
Dim emailAccount As Outlook.Account, tAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim emailStore As Outlook.Store, emailInbox As Outlook.Folder, tMail As Variant

Set emailApplication = New Outlook.Application
Set emailAccounts = emailApplication.Session.Accounts

For Each tAccount In emailAccounts
    If tAccount.DisplayName = "UserEmail@DemoEmail.com" Then: Set emailAccount = tAccount
Next

Set emailStore = emailAccount.DeliveryStore
Set emailInbox = emailStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

On Error Resume Next
For Each tMail In emailInbox.Items
    Debug.Print tMail.SenderEmailAddress
Next
Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is not required:

```
'I think im on the right track here.......
Set iBox = iSelect.SelectedAccount
```

Instead, you may just rely on the `GetDefaultFolder` method which allows retrieving default folders (from the delivery store):

```
Set oFolder = emailNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

If you need to choose a specific store in the profile you may find the required account by using the [Namespace.Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.accounts) property which returns an `Accounts` collection object that represents all the `Account` objects in the current profile. The [Account.DeliveryStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.account.deliverystore) property returns a `Store` object that represents the default delivery store for the account. The [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

> I need to iterate over each e-mail in the inbox ignoring e-mails in any sub folders.

The current folder is processed only when you deal with `Folder.Items` collection.

Comment: Excellent explanation!  You have no idea how many man hours you just saved my entire department.  Thank you so much!